Set image (palplot) into Customtkinter button
How can I set an image (a palplot created with seaborn) into a Customtkinter button (CTkButton)?
In the following MWE, I created the button and the image but adding the image with image = image in the button definition does not work.
MWE
root = CTk()

# Create figure
image = plt.Figure()
ax = image.add_subplot()
# Create canvas to hold figure
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(image, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=1)

ax.imshow(np.arange(500).reshape(1, 500),
          cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(list(color_palette("flare", 500))),
          aspect="auto")
canvas.draw_idle()

# Create button
button = CTkButton(root, text="some button with an image", image = image)
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()


According to the docs the image provided to CTkButton must be a tk.Photoimage. However, it can be a CTkImage as well.
So one way to it is to directly convert the plt.figure to a PIL Image and then implement it as a CTkImage:

from PIL import Image
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkButton, CTkImage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create plot and convert to PIL.Image
plt.imshow([[1,0],[0,1]])
canvas = plt.gcf().canvas
canvas.draw()  # activate renderer for img extraction
img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.buffer_rgba())
plt.close()

# implement Image as a CTkImage in a CTkButton
root = CTk()
plot_img = CTkImage(light_image=img, dark_image=img, size=(200, 170))
button = CTkButton(root, text="some button with an image", image=plot_img)
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()

